# Filtering aggregation results

Tags: elasticsearch

This question is a subquestion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189083/elasticsearch-group-aggregate-respons-by-search-criteria/64191780?noredirect=1#comment113551904_64191780). Posting as a separate question for attention.

**Sample Docs:**

```
{
  "id":1,
  "product":"p1",
  "cat_ids":[1,2,3]
}
{
  "id":2,
  "product":"p2",
  "cat_ids":[3,4,5]
}
{
  "id":3,
  "product":"p3",
  "cat_ids":[4,5,6]
}
```

**Ask:** To get products belonging to a particular category. e.g cat_id = 3

**Query:**

```
GET product/_search 
{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
   "cats": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "cats",
       "size": 10
     },"aggs": {
       "products": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "name.keyword",
           "size": 10
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

**Question:**

1. How to filter the aggregated result for cat_id = 3 here. I tried bucket_selector as well but it is not working.

   **Note:** Due to multi-value of cat_ids filtering and then aggregation isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can [filter values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4), on the basis of which buckets will be created.**

> It is possible to filter the values for which buckets will be created.
> This can be done using the include and exclude parameters which are
> based on regular expression strings or arrays of exact values.
> Additionally, include clauses can filter using partition expressions.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id":1,
  "product":"p1",
  "cat_ids":[1,2,3]
}
{
  "id":2,
  "product":"p2",
  "cat_ids":[3,4,5]
}
{
  "id":3,
  "product":"p3",
  "cat_ids":[4,5,6]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "cats": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cat_ids",
        "include": [                   <-- note this
          3
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "products": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "cats": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 3,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "products": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "p1",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "p2",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```